# Creating a game to guess if the next number will be higher of lower in c

Tags: c

So I am just learning to code now. This is a program running in a terminal on linux.

The game should generate a number between 2-14(a card deck) and let the user guess if the next number will be higher or lower.

The problem I am encountering is that the game works properly but for the game evaluates the numbers from the previous turn. If I get 6 on the first turn, 7 on the second turn and 3 on the third turn and I guessed that the number on the third turn would be higher it will evaluate as a correct guess because the 7 is higher than the 6, not taking the 3 into account as it should.

Also I have a problem with the code creating a new random number when there is incorrect input. It should just keep the same number until the user enters a valid choice.

Example output:

The current card is a 9.
Will the next number be higher(1) or lower(2)?
2

You have guessed incorrectly.
Your current score is -1!
The current number is 9.
Will the next number be higher(1) or lower(2)?
2

The cards are the same.
Your current score is -1!
The current number is 3
Will the next number be higher(1) or lower(2)?

Here is my entire code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{ 
    /*declare variables*/ 
    int pastCard; 
    int currentCard; 
    int score; 
    int userChoice; 
    int playGame = 1; 


    /*set up random*/ 
    int range; 
    srand(time(NULL)); 
    range = (13 - 1) + 1; 

    pastCard = rand() % range + 2; 
    currentCard = rand() % range + 2; 

    while (playGame == 1) 
    { 
        /*change the current card to the past card before creating new current card*/   
        pastCard = currentCard; 

        /*generate a random int for card*/ 

        currentCard = rand() % range + 2; 

        if (currentCard < 11) 
        { 
            printf("The current card is a %d.\n", currentCard); 
        } 
        else if (currentCard == 11) 
        { 
            printf("The current card is a jack.\n", currentCard); 
        } 
        else if (currentCard == 12) 
        { 
            printf("The current card is a queen.\n", currentCard); 
        } 
        else if (currentCard == 13) 
        { 
            printf("The current card is a king.\n", currentCard); 
        } 
        else if (currentCard == 14) 
        { 
            printf("The current card is an ace.\n", currentCard); 
        } 

        printf("Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &userChoice); 
        printf("\n"); 


        if (userChoice == 1) 
        { 
            if (currentCard > pastCard) 
            { 
                score++; 

                printf("You have guessed correctly.\n"); 
                printf("Your current score is %d!\n", score); 
            } 
            else if (currentCard < pastCard) 
            { 
                score--; 

                printf("You have guessed incorrectly.\n"); 
                printf("Your current score is %d!\n", score); 
            } 
            else if (currentCard == pastCard) 
            { 
                printf("The cards are the same.\n"); 
                printf("Your current score is %d!\n", score); 
            } 
        } 
        else if (userChoice == 2) 
        { 
            if (currentCard < pastCard) 
            { 
                score++; 

                printf("You have guessed correctly.\n"); 
                printf("Your current score is %d!\n", score); 
            } 
            else if (currentCard > pastCard) 
            { 
                score--; 

                printf("You have guessed incorrectly.\n"); 
                printf("Your current score is %d!\n", score); 
            } 
            else if (currentCard == pastCard) 
            { 
                printf("The cards are the same.\n"); 
                printf("Your current score is %d!\n", score); 
            } 
        } 
        else if (userChoice == 0) 
        { 
            playGame = 0; 
            printf("Final score: %d\n", score); 

            score = 0; 

            printf("Play again? (press 1 for yes, 0 for no)\n"); 
            scanf("%d", &playGame); 
            printf("\n"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
             printf("Please enter a valid choice.\n"); 
        } 

    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Please help! This has been frustrating me very much!

Comment: Please post your whole code (i.e. something that will compile) and properly indent it.

Comment: You create a new current card in every iteration of the while-loop, no matter whether you have guessed correctly or not before. Do you see that? How about introducing another variable like `char wasLastGuessCorrect`, which you can use for controlling the generation of a new 'currentCard'. Something along the lines of `if (wasLastGuessCorrect == 'y') { pastCard = currentCard; currentCard = rand() % range + 2; }`. Make sure that `wasLastGuessCorrect` will be set to the correct value in all possible scenarios of correct/incorrect/same number guess, so that the if-statement works correctly.

Comment: While we're waiting for the whole code, I'm going to guess that the real problem is that this: `printf("The current number is a % d.\n", currentCard);` should be this: `printf("The current number is a % d.\n", pastCard);` `pastCard` and `currentCard` should probably be changed to `currentCard` and `nextCard`.

Comment: I don't mean to veer off topic, but what is this? (\u201c & \u201d)...are these unicode/hex shortcuts?

Comment: @user2277872: I'd guess probably some copy-paste weirdness.

Comment: Please do not edit everything out of all your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your primary problem by changing:

```
printf("The current number is a %d.\n", currentCard);
```

to:

```
printf("The current number is a %d.\n", pastCard);
```

in all places, since as you've written it, `currentCard` is the one they're trying to guess, not the one you want to show them. You'd improve your program by renaming `pastCard` to `currentCard`, and `currentCard` to `nextCard`, throughout.

Or, with your updated code, change to this:

```
if (pastCard < 11) {
    printf("The current card is a %d.\n", pastCard); 
} else if (pastCard == 11) {
    printf("The current card is a jack.\n", pastCard); 
} else if (pastCard == 12) {
    printf("The current card is a queen.\n", pastCard); 
} else if (pastCard == 13) {
    printf("The current card is a king.\n", pastCard); 
} else if (pastCard == 14) {
    printf("The current card is an ace.\n", pastCard); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a logic error with keeping track of the cards.  You're showing the user the wrong card.  You want to show the current card, wait for input, and THEN choose a new card.

Also, when validating the user input, you can do a loop something like:

```
while user input not valid
    prompt for input
    scan input
    if input not valid then
         print error message
end while
```

Only after this loop should you go on to generate the new card and do the logic checks.